# When using reference with getter in c++ (interface/class)

Tags: c++, interface, reference, getter

I just have an interface class with 2 getters. 1 returns the value of a 'Point' class. I have an other class who uses the interface class so he needs to implement the 2 getters. Like we learned in lessons it's better to use a reference to save storage and cpu. So i tried but my program doesn't work when I use reference with the getPosition() (getter of Point). Here's my code. So my question is. Is there a (genereal) rule when we do and don't use reference with getters in c++. Thanks

Interface : IObject

```
#ifndef IOBJECT_H_
#define IOBJECT_H_

#include "Point.h"

class IObject {
public:
    virtual Point getPosition() const =0;
    virtual double getSize() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

Class: Square.h

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H_
#define SQUARE_H_

#include "IObject.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include <iostream>
class Square : public IObject {
private:
     Point position;
     double size;

protected:
virtual void print(std::ostream& out)const;

public:
Square(const Point& pos, const double size):position(pos), size(size){};
virtual double getSize() const {return this->size;}
virtual Point getPosition() const {return position;}
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Square& s);

};
```

When I return a reference value this is my error at getPosition in Square class.

"Multiple markers at this line
    - Implements IObject::getPosition
    - binding of reference to type 'Point' to a value of type 'const Point' drops 
     qualifiers"

The error says something about the const. I checked that and it makes it more strange because there are no faults about const-use. When I don't use reference my program works fine.

Thank you

Comment: Neither of those getters return a reference. Is *this* the code that exhibits your error ? And if not, wouldnt' returning a `const Point&` address your problem?

Comment: `const` references are perfectly OK as return values from getters, or passing values to setter functions.

Comment: @WhozCraig : the const must be there because I need the 'getPosition()' in other const function

Answer (score 2):

According to error you tried to make your const method to return lvalue (non const) reference, hence the error. Just make it to return const reference instead:

```
virtual const Point &getPosition() const = 0;
```

Note: while passing non trivial type variable by const reference as parameter for efficiency is common practice (and sometimes is unavoidable, like for copy constructor) for returning you may want to avoid it sometimes. On one side using (const) reference would put a requirement to keep such variable inside class instance (you cannot return reference to a local variable) or even worse - static variable, on another returning by value most probably would be as efficient as returning reference, due Return Value Optimization and move semantics and interface could be cleaner that way.

Comment: When i use just Point and no reference it works fine. The const before is not needed.

Comment: @steven do you understand the difference between a *by-value* return result and a *reference* return result? Your "not needed" condition is the former. This answer shows how to do the latter when the getter is `const` (as it usually is).

Comment: @steven open text book and learn what the difference btw pass/return by value and by reference.

Comment: I mean it's not the intention to make the point (position) const because it could chance. The getPosition itself must be const , but that is fine in my code,not? And yes, i understand the difference

Comment: @steven no, your statement shows that you do not understand. Returning const reference does not make `position` member variable unmutable, read the book.

Comment: It makes the reference unmutable, i'm sorry.

Comment: @steven, there is nothing to be sorry about. I sent you to the text book not because I am angry with you, but because good textbook would explain it much better than me.